# Mac, automation of itunes searches of a list of words?

Tags: applescript, automator, copy-paste, automation

I'd like to perform a several searches in the iTunes mac app, pausing until I then resume to do the next search. I have a list of searches I want to perform.

So I either need to produce some kind of automation script, which will give me some kind of button to tap on to resume.

Or I need something which will allow me to paste the next item in my list etc.

I'm basically trying to save some effort from having to type the words each time.

I've had a look at automator, alfred, hazel and the applescript editor. But I don't believe any of these will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like that in Applescript.
iTunes provides a `search` command that gives a reference to a track.

So you can use this command in a loop that:

- Displays a dialog that asks for a search terms.
- A multiple choice dialog shows iTunes matches for this search term.
- You select the desired track from this dialog.
  Then you can play your custom queue one at a time.

Code:

```
set lst_tracks to {}
try
    repeat
        display dialog "Please enter search terms" buttons {"Stop Searching", "Search More"} default button 2 cancel button 1 default answer ""
        set the_text to (text returned of result)
        tell application "iTunes"
            set end of lst_tracks to my GetiTunesTrack(the_text)
        end tell
    end repeat
end try
if lst_tracks ≠ {} then
    set the_result to (display dialog "Start Playing?" buttons {"No", "Yes"} default button 2 cancel button 1)
    set the_button to button returned of the_result
    if the_button = "Yes" then
        try
            repeat with i in lst_tracks
                tell application "iTunes"
                    set the_track to (contents of i)
                    set track_name to name of the_track
                    play the_track
                    set the_result to (display dialog "Playing: " & track_name buttons {"Stop", "Next Track"} default button 2 cancel button 1)
                end tell
            end repeat
        on error
            tell application "iTunes" to stop
        end try
    end if
end if
display dialog "Finish"

on GetiTunesTrack(search_str)
    local lst_names

    set lst_names to {}
    tell application "iTunes"
        set lst_results to (search library playlist 1 for search_str)

        repeat with item_ref in lst_results
            set end of lst_names to name of item_ref
        end repeat

        set the_selection to item 1 of (choose from list lst_names with prompt "Choose a Track" default items (item 1 of lst_names))
        set the_track to first track of library playlist 1 whose (name is the_selection)
        return the_track
    end tell
end GetiTunesTrack
```

Comment: Thanks however I need to search the App Store and view the result then repeat after a hotkey or something

Comment: No problem. ¿It's the iOS App Store? If so, maybe there is a solution.

Comment: No it's the App Store page in the iTunes Mac app